# shell script does not give wait RMAN block to complete before sending an email

Tags: bash, shell

Hope you all doing well.

I have an ORACLE standby database where in we are checking for block corrpution everyday twice at 3 and 6 o clock and we are using the below shell script with rman run block to check it. THe problem is it does not wait for the rman block to complete before sending an output. May I know your suggestions if I need to modify it please.

prsl_phl_blk_chk.sh
++++++++++++++++++++

```
MAIL_ID="abcd@google.com"
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oowner/product/11.2.0.4/dbhome_1
export ORACLE_SID=ABCD_STBY
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
NLS_DATE_FORMAT="dd-MON-YYYY hh24:mi:ss"; export NLS_DATE_FORMAT
nohup rman target=/ @/scripts/rman_blk_check.scr > /scripts/log/ABCD_STBY_logicalblk_chk_25SEP2017.log 2>&1 &
mail -s "ABCD_STBY logical Block Corruption check  on `date`" ${MAIL_ID} < /scripts/log/ABCD_STBY_logicalblk_chk_25SEP2017.log


rman_blk_check.scr
++++++++++++++++++
run
{
allocate channel c1 type disk;
allocate channel c2 type disk;
backup validate check logical database;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `&` from the end of the `nohup` line, the `rman` command will run to completion before `mail` runs.

```
nohup rman target=/ @/scripts/rman_blk_check.scr > /scripts/log/ABCD_STBY_logicalblk_chk_25SEP2017.log 2>&1
```

The `&` tells `bash` to run the `rman` command in the background, which isn't what you want.

I'd note that running only `rman` under `nohup` is a bit strange. Presumably the rest of the script should be protected from interruptions, too.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your inputs.